# Why can't I see "Temporary Tables" under "tempdb" in VS Code?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code, sql-server-express

I've worked with VS Code as my primary IDE for about 6 months and I think this has worked before. At least I can't remember that this would have been a problem. But, I also run Msn SSMS so if I'm mistaken and this never have worked I do apologize for the question.

When I create temporary tables in SQL Server and SQL Server Express I can see them in "Temporary Tables" under "tempdb". When I got back to work after a couple of weeks away and started up VS Code again I couldn't see the "Temporary Tables" in VS Code anymore (the red mark in the picture below)??? I do believe I could see them before the summer. I've tried to look in the setup json-file in VS Code, but couldn't figure out what might be missing.

[image: How it looks in SSMS]

I can see the tables using Msn SSMS.

It might be worth mentioning that all my database connections in VS Code was faulty when I got back so I had to set them up again. Everything is setup to get user access from my user account in the environment where we have the databases. I have no access to OS setup or administration tools.

VS Code version is 1.59.0
The SQL Servers I'm connecting to is one SQL Server Express (believe it's 14) and one SQL Server (believe this also is 14).

What should I do to see temporary tables in VS Code?

Comment: The hint is in the name: **temporary** tables. The tables you saw were *temporary*; you can't see them anymore as they don't exist any more.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but before they are "dead" they are visble in the database tempdb, as in my attached screenshot, where it shows the temporary table #t, created by a script run in VS Code, where it does'nt show up, but I can see it in VS Code. So I just want to be able to see them as long as they are "alive" even in VS Code. :)